# What does "unevaluated" mean in desctiption of "typeof" operator?

Tags: javascript, typeof

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof):

> The typeof operator returns a string indicating the type of the **unevaluated** operand.

Could you say, please, what does "unevaluated" mean in this description?

---

Because in `typeof func()` function is called (which is reasonably, but a bit inconsistency with aforementioned description):

```js
function func() {
  console.log('func is called');
  return 0;
}

console.log(typeof func());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is highly misleading terminology. Of course `typeof` needs to evaluate its operand to a value to determine the type of the value!

There's only one notable exception, and this is probably what the "unevaluated" refers to: `typeof` does not evaluate unresolvable references. If you use an identifier that has not been declared anywhere, evaluating it would usually throw an exception (in strict mode at least). However, `typeof` will just tell you that it's `"undefined"`.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the question:

> The typeof operator returns a string indicating the type of the unevaluated operand.

Unevaluated operand means a value that has not yet been checked for its type.

---

You are calling typeof on the integer that the function returns. So, you get a number, like this:

```js
function func() {
  console.log('func is called');
  return 0;
}

console.log(typeof func());
```

---

To pass the function as a parameter you would write `console.log(typeof func);` without the parentheses `()` on `func`.

**Note:** the function doesn't get called here

```js
function func() {
      console.log('func is called');
      return 0;
    }

    console.log(typeof func);
```